# Use a enable_if that does not depend on method's template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae

I'm trying to use `std::enable_if` and SFINAE to switch out the implementation of a class template's method based purely on the template parameters of the class. Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T1, class T2>
class Foo {
    template<class InnerT, class ... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T1, T2>::value, void>::type
    bar(InnerT param) {};

    template<class InnerT, class ... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T1, T2>::value, void>::type
    bar(InnerT param) {};
};


int main() {
    Foo<int, int> f;
}
```

Here, `bar()` should behave differently based on whether `T1` and `T2` are the same type or not. However, this code does not compile. Neither GCC nor clang tell me anything useful. I suspect the problem is that the `std::enable_if` condition does not depend on the parameters of `bar()`, i.e., not on its *immediate context* as specified in paragraph 17.8.2, point 8, of the standard.

This assumption is supported by the fact that this code compiles fine:

```
#include <type_traits>

class DummyClass {};

template<class T1, class T2>
class Foo {
    template<class InnerT, class ... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T1, T2>::value || 
                            std::is_same<InnerT, DummyClass>::value, void>::type
    bar(InnerT param) {};

    template<class InnerT, class ... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T1, T2>::value || 
                            std::is_same<InnerT, DummyClass>::value, void>::type
    bar(InnerT param) {};
};


int main() {
    Foo<int, int> f;
}
```

Now the expression inside the `std::enable_if` depends on the "immediate context", namely `InnerT`, even though that part of the expression always evaluates to `false`.

It looks like I can use this as a workaround, but that feels really hacky and ugly. How do you solve this problem "correctly"? A thought I had was to add an additional template parameter (call it `DummyType`) to `bar()`, which defaults to e.g. `DummyType = T1`, and then check `std::is_same<DummyType, T2>`, but the fact that `bar()` takes a parameter pack makes this impossible (or does it…?)

Comment: Well, with C++17 you can always turn `bar()` into a wrapper that uses `if constexpr` to invoke one of the two actual alternate methods.

Comment: "or does it...?" -- It doesn't. Doing exactly what you guessed won't work, will work.

Comment: The "correct"(TM) solution would probably be not to force the use of SFINAE, but rather do tag dispatch instead.

Comment: @hvd: But if I add the DummyType as second template parameter, and then later pass a list of template arguments that should go into the pack - how does the compiler now that the second argument should not go into DummyType, but be the first thing that's part of Args?

Comment: @LukasBarth Don't add it as the second parameter, add it as the last.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather than try to SFINAE your way into two implementations, just use normal overload resolution.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T1, class T2>
class Foo {
    template<class InnerT, class ... Args>
    void do_bar(InnerT param, std::true_type, Args... args) { std::cout << "same" << std::endl; }

    template<class InnerT, class ... Args>
    void do_bar(InnerT param, std::false_type, Args... args) { std::cout << "not same" << std::endl; }

public:
    template<class InnerT, class ... Args>
    void bar(InnerT&& param, Args&&... args) 
    {
        do_bar(std::forward<InnerT>(param), std::is_same<T1, T2>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

};

int main() {
    Foo<int, int> f1;
    Foo<int, double> f2;

    f1.bar(1, 2, 3);
    f2.bar("Hello");
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afff4afecc9d71cf)

Comment: While every C++ std does it, is `is_same<int,int>` guaranteed to descend from `true_type`, or is that only true of `is_same<int,int>::type`?  I should check.

Comment: "A BinaryTypeTrait describes a relationship between two types. ... It shall be ... **publicly and unambiguously derived, directly or indirectly, from its base characteristic**, which is a specialization of the template integral_­constant" [`[meta.rqmts]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.rqmts#def:BinaryTypeTrait)

Comment: thanks!  I've used that lots, and had always meant to check.

Answer (score 8):

To expand from the comments:

> A thought I had was to add an additional template parameter (call it `DummyType`) to `bar()`, which defaults to e.g. `DummyType = T1`, and then check `std::is_same<DummyType, T2>`, but the fact that `bar()` takes a parameter pack makes this impossible (or does it…?)

It doesn't. Doing exactly what you guessed won't work, will work.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T1, class T2>
struct Foo {
    template<class InnerT, class ... Args, class DummyType = T1>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<DummyType, T2>::value, void>::type
    bar(InnerT param) {};

    template<class InnerT, class ... Args, class DummyType = T1>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<DummyType, T2>::value, void>::type
    bar(InnerT param) {};
};


int main() {
    Foo<int, int> f;
    f.bar(3);                   // InnerT = int; Args = empty; DummyType = int.
    f.bar<int, void, short>(4); // InnerT = int; Args = void, short; DummyType = int.
}
```

> But if I add the DummyType as second template parameter, and then later pass a list of template arguments that should go into the pack - how does the compiler now that the second argument should not go into DummyType, but be the first thing that's part of Args?

That's why I added as the last parameter. Template non-pack parameters are allowed to follow template pack parameters if they have a default. The compiler will use all explicitly specified arguments for `Args`, and will use `DummyType = T1` no matter which arguments you specify.

Comment: Today I learned…! I wasn't aware that defaulted parameters may follow after template packs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I suspect the problem is that the enable_if condition does not depend on the parameters of bar,

Exactly.

> A thought I had was to add an additional template parameter (call it DummyType) to bar, which defaults to e.g. DummyType = T1, and then check std::is_same

I usually see exactly this solution.

> but the fact that bar takes a parameter pack makes this impossible (or does it…?)

No if you place `DummyType` before `InnerT`

```
   template <typename D1 = T1, typename InnerT, typename ... Args>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<D1, T2>::value>::type
   bar (InnerT param) { std::cout << "- true version" << std::endl; }

   template <typename D1 = T1, typename InnerT, typename ... Args>
   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<D1, D2>::value>::type
   bar (InnerT param) { std::cout << "- false version" << std::endl; }
```

This works perfectly.

The drawback of this solution is that you can "hijack" `bar()` explicating the `D1` type

```
Foo<int, int> f;

f.bar(0);        // print "- true version"
f.bar<long>(0);  // print "- false version"
```

but you can solve this problem imposing that `T1` is that same as `D1`

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct Foo {
   template <typename D1 = T1, typename InnerT, typename ... Args>
   typename std::enable_if<   std::is_same<D1, T2>::value
                           && std::is_same<D1, T1>::value>::type
   bar (InnerT param) { std::cout << "- true version" << std::endl; }

   template <typename D1 = T1, typename InnerT, typename ... Args>
   typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_same<D1, T2>::value
                           && std::is_same<D1, T1>::value>::type
   bar (InnerT param) { std::cout << "- false version" << std::endl; }
};
```

Now you can't "hijack" `bar()` anymore.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand that correctly, explicating the D1 type still "hijacks" the dummy, right? It just produces an error then. That's probably not acceptable in my case, since I'm modifying some library's API function, and it would be bad if this introduced compile errors into existing code… The solution by @hvd seems to overcome this, though!

Comment: @LukasBarth - "If I understand that correctly, explicating the D1 type still "hijacks" the dummy, right?" Right. But you can impose that `D1` is equal to `T1`. And I'm agree: hvd's solution is better than mine. But give a look also at the Caleth's solution (the tag dispatching one): avoids completely SFINAE and is (IMHO) very elegant.